# Decimal values for yAxis categories in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need my yAxis categories to be 0 = 'Poor', 0.25 = 'Below Average', 0.75 = 'Average' 1="Good"

I set the categories right, but Highcharts seems to interpret each point I plot to be equal to "1" step on the yAxis. See http://jsfiddle.net/54cFG/

Ideally, that chart should *always* show 4 labels on the yAxis and the plotted points should line up at "Below Average" and "Average".

Is there a setting I'm missing? I think I pretty much tried everything at http://www.highcharts.com/ref/

Comment: Probably not what you want but it might solve this issue: Since your yAxis is actually your "value" why not use plotBands instead to mark which yAxis values are in poor, below average, average, or good? See http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-plot-bands

Comment: @Naren ~ What is the status on this question?  Were you ever able to come to an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 6):

You could always use plot bands to display categories on the Y axis.  That way you could still keep the actual values.  I have demonstrated that with your code [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/54cFG/1/).

**EDIT**

Here is another [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/54cFG/3/) with the grid lines taken off and the plotBands each with their own color.  Here is the [**color chart**](http://www.december.com/html/spec/colorrgbadec.html) if you wan to change any of them.

If you prefer to use the plot bands and no y-axis labels, here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/54cFG/4/) of that.  I think it works just fine.  If the user really wants to see the exact value they can hover over the point.

Comment: I would also add in to your yAxis:             labels: {
                enabled: false
            }, so that the numeric values are not shown.

Comment: @Wergeld I do agree, sometimes the values may make it to busy.  Also, the grid lines could make it look weird also.